# Почему не передаются данные через сокеты?

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, сокеты

Есть сервер, который запускается из главного класса:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DriverClassServer {
    public void startServer() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
            while (true) {
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                PrintWriter toClient =new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(),true);
                toClient.println("Connected!");
                toClient.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DriverClassClient extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("logInAsDriver.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DriverClassClient().connectToServer();
            }
        });
        th.start();
        launch(args);
    }

    public void connectToServer() {
        String message = "";
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);

            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            System.out.println("Suc");
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Get info : " + reader.readLine());
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске сервера, а потом клиента, вместо `Get info : connected` выводится `Get info : null`

```
Suc
Get info : null
окт 02, 2018 9:17:42 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.171 by 
JavaFX 
runtime of version 8.0.162
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два раза используете `readLine()`: один раз в условии цикла и второй раз в теле цикла, а посылаете только одну строку.

```
while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Get info : " + message );
}
```